# Determine all entire functions $f$ with $\Re f(z) > 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that, $f(0) = 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am trying to determine all entire functions $f$ with $\Re f(z) > 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that, $f(0) = 1$.

So far, my attempt is the following. Write $f = u+iv$, and define the function 
$$
g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{\Re f(z)} = \frac{u(z)+iv(z)}{u(z)} = 1 + i \frac{v(z)}{u(z)}. 
$$
Since $\Re f(z) > 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, this is an entire function. We have 
$$
1 = g(0) = 1 + i \frac{v(0)}{u(0)}
$$
So $v(0) = 0$. Also, 
$$
|g(z)|^2 = 1 + \frac{v(z)^2}{u(z)^2}. 
$$
I want to apply Liousville Theorem somehow, so I'm looking for bounds, i.e. 
$$
|g(z)| \leq M|z|^m
$$
for some $M$, $m \geq 0$, and for large enough $|z|$. I have no progress on this so far, I'm not sure if my attempt is in the right direction.

Comment: Hint: [little Picard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem). If you want to use [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29), apply it to $e^{-f(z)}$

Comment: In addition, I think a priori its not clear that your $g$ is analytic

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! Indeed, I defined the wrong function. It seems that considering $g(z) = e^{-f(z)}$ is a good approach in this setting.